# Change axis scale with LogAxisRenderer

Tags: javascript, web-applications, formatting, plot, jqplot

I plot data with [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) using [logAxisRenderer](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-logAxisRenderer-js.html) to have two logarithmic axes.

Everything is fine except of two problems:

1. jqPlot creates a lot of empty space between 0 and 1.
2. There are two zeros on the x-axis, since I format the numbers to "%'i" (one for 0.0 and one for 0.5).

I tried to use min:1 and max:100000 in order to hide the empty space and the zeros. But this didn't work. The resulting plot has no line and all x-axis labels are on the same spot on the left side of the axis.

Here is the code I use to create this plot:

```
$.jqplot(divId, [ line ], {
    title : title,
    series:[{showMarker:false}],
    axes : {
        xaxis : {
            label:'Users',
            renderer : $.jqplot.LogAxisRenderer,
            tickOptions:{
                tickDistribution: "power",
                formatString: "%'i"
            },
            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
        },
        yaxis : {
            label:'Frequency',
            renderer : $.jqplot.LogAxisRenderer,
            tickOptions:{
                tickDistribution:"power",
                formatString: "%'i"
            },
            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use force ticks to solve this problem:

```
$.jqplot(divId, [ line ], {
    title : title,
    series:[{showMarker:false}],
    axes : {
        xaxis : {
            label:'Users',
            renderer : $.jqplot.LogAxisRenderer,
            ticks: [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000],
            tickOptions:{
                tickDistribution: "power",
                formatString: "%'i"
            },
            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
        },
        // ...
    },
});
```

This does not really solve your problem in a general way, but it does help. For me (jqPlot 1.0.4r1121) setting "min: 1" results in the behaviour you described. Settings both "min: 1" and "max: 10000" works for me but does not set power distributed ticks but even spaced ones.